# How to get the segments of a path geometry in Direct2D?

Tags: direct2d

The following picture show a path geometry in Direct2D, it contains 5 segments, each segment is a straight line, my request is that, given such a hill, i want to get all the 5 lines.

[image]

but it seems there is no related API can get the segments of a path geometry in Direct2D, I see the ID2D1PathGeometry interface provide a method GetSegmentCount, if we can not get the segments, why Microsoft provide this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `ID2D1PathGeometry::Stream()`. You will have to write a class that implements `ID2D1GeometrySink`. You may find it useful to implement this in a generalized sense such that instead of looking for the exact data that you need now, it can pump out an object tree. If you need an example for what type of object model to use, look no further than WPF's `System.Windows.Media.Geometry` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry.aspx ).

You can also easily convert from those classes back to `ID2D1PathGeometry`, and use whichever is most comfortable or appropriate for any situation. I've written both conversions and found it to be pretty straightforward once I realized they were using the same "language." I especially found that it helped to organize my understanding as to the difference between "figures" and "segments."

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but, this does not suit for my request, if I implement ID2D1GeometrySink, I need to build up the path geometry myself in order to get the segments, but, my path geometry was not build by myself, I got it from another function.

Comment: If that's not what you're looking for then I'm not even sure I understand what you're asking for ... you asked for something to give you the segments of a path geometry, and that's exactly what that does!

You can also use `ID2D1Geometry::Simplify` to stream any geometry into an `ID2D1SimplifiedGeometrySink`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I want to state my request once more, I want to get the segments of a path geometry,that's the lines, arcs and curves which compose the path geometry, my example above only contains lines, I am sorry if that's confused you. I have no chance to implement the interface you mentioned, since I get the path geometry from this function GetGlyphRunOutline. The ID2D1Geometry::Simplify method only get the Geometry Sink, not the segments. am I clear now?

Comment: Yes, you were already clear, and that's exactly what I answered.

Comment: To further clarify this, look at methods like `ID2D1SimplifiedGeometrySink::AddBeziers()`. Each 'add' method is basically just a command saying "hey here's a new segment for the current figure." And that's where you get the segments. In your case you're specifically interested in when `AddLines()` gets called. It sounds like you have a path geometry which contains 1 figure, which then contains 1 segment, and that segment is a "poly line segment" which just has the points for the polygon.

Honestly it makes a lot more sense if you look at the WPF object model for this :)

Comment: Hi Rick, I must state it again, i get the path geometry from function GetGlyphRunOutline, so I have no chance to call function such as AddLines.

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding. You have a path geometry. **We get that.** You then have to implement your own class that implements ID2D1GeometrySink. You pass an instance of that to Stream(). Then it calls YOUR implementation of AddLines, _which is what gives you the segments_. I don't know how I can make this any clearer!

Comment: Why should I call AddLines? I don't need to add anything to the path geometry, I just want to get what it has already- the segments.

Comment: Hi Rick, I mark your answer as accepted, although it does not resolve the problem, it does provide lots of ideas which can help me in the future. thanks for digging this issue so deep, and thank for your patient.

Comment: You don't call AddLines. Direct2D calls your implementation of AddLines on your geometry sink. Push versus pull.

Comment: I am confused, when will Direct2D call it?

Comment: If you can't figure it out from what I've already replied with, then it really just doesn't matter. I'm done here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a PathGeometry, then using PathGeometry::Stream() is good.

However, if you have a basic Geometry and you want to accomplish the same, then you can do the following:

1. Implement your own GeometrySink to "catch" the geometry components
2. Create an empty PathGeometry
3. Use Geometry::Combine to combine (union) your geometry with the empty geometry.

The results will be deposited in your GeometrySink.

Comment: The `ID2D1Geometry::Simplify()` method is probably preferable to doing a union with empty geometry.

Comment: ID2D1Geometry::Simplfy() gives an undesirable effect of putting holes when shapes overlap.  Combine (union) does not.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to keep that in mind if I see anything like that!

Answer (score 0):

implement a class named SpecializedSink that inherits from the ID2D1SimplifiedGeometrySink interface, the extended **AddLines** method called by ID2D1Geometry::**Simplify** to retrieves the geometry data.

suggest you read the [example for retrieve data from geometry] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee453682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx by extending ID2D1SimplifiedGeometrySink.

Comment: I have no chance to call AddLines, I get the path geometry from another API, I didn't build up it myself.